# How to automatically deploy asp.net core application to ec2 instance using jenkins?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, jenkins, amazon-ec2, asp.net-core

I have hosted an **ASP.NET Core** web application on an **EC2** instance using **Nginx**. The EC2 isntance is running on **Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS** machine.

I am developing the code in windows machine and publishing the code. Then copying the files into the EC2 instance using **WinSCP**. The web application is running nicely and i can hit the application using postman or browser.

Now, i have decided to use **jenkins** for CI/CD. I have installed jenkins in the same ec2 server where my web application running. Jenkins is running in port **8080** and my web application is running in port **80**. I have configured jenkins with my bitbucket repository by following this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNaR5Q_pIa4&index=4&list=PLzvRQMJ9HDiSaisKr7OnM4Fl7JXCDDcmt).

Now, my jenkins server is up and running. If i commit anything in the bitbucket repository, jenkins server automatically triggers a build.

Previously, i have published the code using below command:

```
dotnet publish -o my-sample-site
```

And then copied the files from **my-sample-site** directory to the directory in EC2 instance. Now, i want to automatically build the asp.net core web source codes and publish the codes to the folder where my web application is running. I may have to restart the service also after changing the codes.

What should i include in the jenkins build step so that whenever `bitbucket repository` changes triggers build in `jenkins`, it will build the asp.net core source codes and then publish the codes in the directory of the `EC2` instance where my web application is running.

How should i do this automatically? Any reference please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not an expert on jenkins, but you could definatelly do what you ask with gulp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set up CI/CD server using Jenkins connected to a Bitbucket repository for an ASP.NET Core Web API running in an EC2 instance. Anyone can check my article [**here**](https://medium.com/@setu677/how-to-set-up-ci-cd-server-using-jenkins-connected-to-a-bitbucket-repository-for-an-asp-net-c2b9fced09d5).